# EF CF: How to remove FK Reference Constraint?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship

everyone.
I need to delete some entities without any conditions. Everything is handled by code.

But EF doesn't allow me to do that. I can manually remove FK reference constraint via SSMS, but how can I set it on creating DB?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: Can you please improve the question?

Comment: I need to remove all FK_REFERENCE_CONSTRAINT in every table on DB creating